# Why doesn't my page refresh on form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've made a simple quiz application with one question to answer; when the user submits the form the answer is posted to a MySQL database. Then a function is run that does a database query and translates the data in the database table to JSON, which I then visualize using a D3 script.

The full code is [here on github](https://github.com/radiocontrolled/quiz) and I've included snippets below.

My question: index.php page first loads,  [a D3 script takes the JSON and builds a small bar chart which is displayed next to the from](https://github.com/radiocontrolled/quiz/blob/master/js/main.js). Screenshot is [here](https://github.com/radiocontrolled/quiz/blob/f2f0c2925acd57e237d1a8426cbc4976111bed83/screenshot.png).

The problem I am having is that after the user submits the form, although the database is updated correctly, the page isn't refreshed. This means the JSON and the bar chart aren't updated.

I have to manually refresh (command-r) in order to see the correct (updated) visualization.

What I am trying to accomplish: to get the chart to refresh when "Submit" is pressed so the updated results are presented to the user.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and could use a pointer on whether I need to be looking at the PHP or JavaScript side to get the chart to refresh (and the page to reload the updated JSON) on form submit.

Index.php:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
     <fieldset>
     <legend>Choose your favourite option:</legend>
     <label>Susan <input type="radio" name="author" id="Susan" value="Susan"></label><br/>
     <label>Camile <input type="radio" name="author" id="Camile" value="Camile"></label><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

main.js

```
 var ele = document.getElementById("form");

  if(ele.addEventListener){
    ele.addEventListener("submit", reload, false);  //Modern browsers
  } 
  else if (ele.attachEvent){
    ele.attachEvent('onsubmit', reload);            //Old IE
  }

  function reload() {
    window.location.reload();
    console.log("reloaded");
    drawChart();
  };
```

form.php

```
 include "toJson.php";
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "quiz");

  if (!$link) {
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $update = "INSERT INTO `quiz`.`answers` (`name`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['author']) .  "')";

  mysqli_query($link, $update);

  updateJson();

  mysqli_close($link);
```

toJson.php

```
$location = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: " . $location);

function updateJson () {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "quiz");

  if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `answers`");

  $arr = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
  $arr[] = $row;
  print_r($row);
  echo "<br/>";
 }

 //write to json file
 $fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr));
 fclose($fp);

  mysqli_close($link);

  }

  updateJson();
```

Comment: Is the form being posted via AJAX? If it isn't, and your form.php file is exactly as you've posted then when you submit the form you should be seeing a blank page with the URL ending in /form.php

Comment: More likely to be a client-side issue, we need the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Force the javascript to reload, just in case it's trying to read the cache or something:

```
window.location.reload();
```

to

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

> forcedReload Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing current solution, i would like to propose a better solution. if you use ajax to post your data to server and get a json response back, which you can use to render your chart. you can also use ajax form plugin to apply to your current form.